# How to add single quotes around alphabets in the strings I create in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can I know how to add the character ' in the Excel VBA code before and after an alphabet is typed out. I need this to be for a length of 25 characters.

For eg., If a sentence says, "I AM GOOD" then I need to be as...

'I'

'A'
'M'

'G'
'O'
'O'
'D'

I have a script and I need to add this particular feature in it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

CODE: -

```
Sub aaa()

    Dim buff() As String
    Dim my_string As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    my_string = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
    ReDim buff(Len(my_string) - 1)

    For i = 1 To Len(my_string)

        buff(i - 1) = Mid$(my_string, i, 1)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = buff(i - 1)

            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = " " Then

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = "[right]"

                For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:B25")
                    If Len(rng) = 0 Then
                           rng.Value = "[right]"
                    End If
                Next rng

           End If

    Next
  
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try anything?   Seems you could do it pretty simply while (or after) populating `buf`.  What happens when you do that?

Comment: Add expected input/output also add screenshots. Also add a screenshot, showing what you actually get and point out how it differs from what you want